# Performance profiling java reactive application

Tags: java, project-reactor

JVM has a great set of tools to find the hotspots in your application.
By enabling JMX and connecting with JProfiler / VisualVm we can quite quickly find methods that take most time in our workflow.

However, reactive application (project-reactor) slices our workflow in unnamed tasks that may accept random threads. What is more, waiting for external resources is done in reactive manner, so we won't see that given access has blocked our workflow.

Do you have any ideas how to profile reactive application efficiently?
I would like to avoid inserting some probes in code and doing it by logging.

Project reactor solved problem with shuttered stacktraces by introducing agent that gathers stacktraces when bubbling the error up, thus we can see the whole image of where was our program at the time of an error.

What about profiling? Although methods that take some time by themselves (like fanaout when iterating on collections) will be spotted, most common problems that involve db or external services access will be not.

Looking for your opinions.
Regards

Comment: check JMH Benchmarking Project :- https://github.com/openjdk/jmh

Comment: @AmolGharpure thanks for commenting. I am looking for a tool that will work as jprofiler/asyncprofiler in nin-reactive apps. More like flame graphs that show which methods take most time and where are the hotspots that I could optimize. As far as I know jmh is a benchmark that can be used to find whether given workflow meets timing criteria, but it will not find the exact spot that is responsible for poor performance

Comment: Questions asking us to [recommend or find a book](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @aled I appreciate your answer, but have you really read my question? The problem: finding hotspots in reactive application. What has been tried: I have used typical tools like visualVm to sample cpu. But the nature of reactive application makes it unusable

Comment: I was answering more to your previous comment: "I am looking for a tool that will work as jprofiler/asyncprofiler in nin-reactive apps"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one solution could be to use a tracing system like sleuth/zipkin that would give you times across services and external calls.
Then track down which service takes time depending on the request and then track with your visualvm
Also the zipkin can be used on prod afterwards if needed to keep tracking bottlenecks

For example a /first calls a /second service, all in reactor. The first has a sleep of 1.5s to simulate a slow response time.
[image]

**To add specific method tracking**
either register a bean

```
@Bean
    public ObservedAspect observedAspect(ObservationRegistry observationRegistry) {
        return new ObservedAspect(observationRegistry);
    }
```

then you can use the **@Observed** annotation on the method you want to track.

or use a decorator around a specific method (or directly create in the method but it's not clean)

```
Observation observation = Observation.start("MyImpl.findOne", observationRegistry);
```

and do not forget to observation.stop()

Comment: I know that zipkin automatically can track external calls (via grpc) or to db (littleharder, but doable with r2dbc).  How would you get timing of internal calls withing reactive application, like you mentioned, calls to services inside the app? Have you inserted some probes  by yourself in code?

Comment: Edited post for tracking calls inside the app

Comment: That looks really good. This could be the answer